# Is that possible, DbContext.SaveChanges() returns 0 but doesn't have an exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I use Entity Framework 4.0. Is it possible that `SaveChanges()` returns 0 but doesn't throw an exception? For example, after adding.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    _context.CodeProducts.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    //Shell I control return result from SaveChanges() in here.
    //However doesn't throw an exceoption?

    return new MethodResponse()
    {
        ResultText = "Successful",
        Type = MethodResponse.ResponseType.Succeed
    };
}
catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException exc)
{
    throw exc;
}
catch (UpdateException exc)
{
    throw exc;
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    throw exc;
}
```

Comment: You need to add more information otherwise nobody will be able to help. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), the return value of `DbContext.SaveChanges` is

> The number of objects written to the underlying database.

So what you see is only possible, when no entities needed to be saved to the database.

Comment: That's right - for example: if you delete a row that does not exist any longer you will get 0 affected rows

Comment: @CarstenKönig No, if you delete a row that doesn't exist anymore, the database will return "0 rows affected", and EF will translate that into an exception. "no entities needed to be saved" means there were no changes in the context before `SaveChanges` was called.

Comment: really? Have to try it but I think I had similiar issues in the past without getting a exception but thank you for the correction

Comment: And if it returns -1?

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework's `db.SaveChanges()` for deletes and saves returns the number rows being affected. In test using the Fakes Framework (stubs and shims), however, the value returned will always be 0.

If there is an error in the call, then an exception will be thrown.  The implication is that any calling method relying on a value greater than zero returned from `db.SaveChanges()` for confirmation cannot be tested for that same value.

This may prove critical when a method is using the `db.SaveChanges()` return value to evaluate the number of rows affected in a given operation.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that if you update an entity and there aren't actually any changes to it `SaveChangesAsync()` will return `0` and `Exception` will be `null`.

Comment: Does that mean SaveChangesAsync()  will throw a null exception?

Comment: No - it means that there is null/no exception.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not mentioning about `DbContext`, but if someone is using `XEntities` and getting same problem, you can try:

```
using (var entities = new XEntities())
{
    var product = entities.Products.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    product.Type = "New type"; // modifying

    int flag = entities.SaveChanges(); // 1
    // or await entities.SaveChangesAsync(); // 1
}
```

The problem:

```
public class Demo
{
    private XEntities _entities = new XEntities();

    public void Test(int id)
    {
        var product = _entities.Product.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        product.Type = "New type"; // modifying

        int flag = _entities.SaveChanges(); // 0 <<<====
        // or await entities.SaveChangesAsync(); // 0  <<<====

        // you need to create new instance of XEntities to apply changes
    }
}
```